# MySQL join multiple rows of query into one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

### Table structure

**client_commands** (the "main" table):
`id | completed`

**command_countries**:
`id | command_id | country_code`

**command_os**:
`id | command_id |OS`

command_id on references the id column on client_commands.

### Problem

I can add client commands with filters based on countries and operating systems. To try and normalise my DB structure, for each new command added:

- Add a new row to client_commands
- For each country, I add a new row to command_countries, each referencing client_command.id
- For each OS, I add a new row to command_os, each referencing client_command.id

For one of the pages on my site, I need to display all client_commands (where completed = 0) as well as all the countries and operating systems for that command. My desired output would be something like:

```
id | countries | OS
1  | GB, US, FR| 2, 3
2  | ES, HU    | 1, 3
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this. The current query I'm using returns multiple rows:

```
SELECT a.id, b.country_code, c.OS
FROM client_commands a
LEFT JOIN command_countries b on b.command_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN command_os c on c.command_id = a.id
WHERE a.completed = 0
```

[image: Query results]

Any help?

Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to mention (if you couldn't infer from above) - there can be a different number of operating systems and countries per command.

--

Also: I know I could do this by pulling all the commands, then looping through and running 2 additional queries for each result. But if I can, I'd like to do it as efficiently as possible with one query.

Comment: `SELECT a.id, GROUP_CONCAT(b.country_code), GROUP_CONCAT(c.OS)
FROM client_commands a
LEFT JOIN command_countries b on b.command_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN command_os c on c.command_id = a.id
WHERE a.completed = 0
GROUP BY a.id`

Comment: @Mihai Worked when I added DISTINCT, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in one query by using `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT a.id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.country_code SEPARATOR ' ,') `countries`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  c.OS SEPARATOR ' ,') `os`, 
FROM client_commands a
LEFT JOIN command_countries b on b.command_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN command_os c on c.command_id = a.id
WHERE a.completed = 0
GROUP BY a.id
```

if you want the ordered results in in a row you can use ORDER BY in `GROUP_CONCAT` like

```
GROUP_CONCAT(b.country_code ORDER BY b.command_id DESC SEPARATOR ' ,') `countries`
```

But  be aware of that fact it has a limit of 1024 character to concat set by default but this can be increased b,steps provided in [**manual**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Hey - this sort of works. But sometimes I'll have a different number of countries to operating systems per command. Your query has a result of: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/3myywml11pazgf9/hz4s0rzf.png

Comment: @Prash you can use `DISTINCT` in `GROUP_CONCAT` so it will not repeat the same values